# Python Sudoku Checker 9X9

Tags: python

```
while True:
    try:
        file = input("Enter a filename: ") 
        fi = open(file, "r")
        infile = fi.read()
        grid = [list (i) for i in infile.split()] #Puts the sudoku puzzle into a list in     order to check that the total number is valid
        check = len(grid)
        print("The total number in this puzzle is:",check) #Counts the amount of numbers in the sudoku puzzle
        break
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print ("The inputted file does not exist")

def check(infile):
    count = 0
    for j in range (0,9):
        for n in range(0,9):
            if infile[j].count(infile[j][n]) <= 1:
                count = count + 0
            else:
                count = count + 1

cols = [[row[i] for row in infile] for i in[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]
leg = 0
for i in range(0,9):
    for j in range(0,9):
        if cols[i].count(cols[i][j]) <= 1:
            leg = leg + 0
        else:
                leg = leg + 1

angel = []
for t in range(3):
    ang = infile[t]
    for u in range(3):
        angel.append(ang[u])

        foot = 0
        for be in range(9):
            if angel.count(angel[be]) <= 1:
                foot = foot + 0
            else:
                    foot = foot + 1


if count + leg + foot == 0:
    print("Valid")
else:
    print ("Invalid")


def inputs():
    x = raw_input()
    ls = []
    while x != '':
        x1 =x.split(' ')
        ls.append(x1)
        if len(infile) >=9:
            print (check(infile))
            infile = []
            x = raw_input()
inputs()
```

actual error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Computer Programming/Assignment/check 2.py", line 22, in <module>
    cols = [[row[i] for row in infile] for i in[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]
  File "E:/Computer Programming/Assignment/check 2.py", line 22, in <listcomp>
    cols = [[row[i] for row in infile] for i in[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]
  File "E:/Computer Programming/Assignment/check 2.py", line 22, in <listcomp>
    cols = [[row[i] for row in infile] for i in[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Why does it give an output to say that my string index is out of range, is there another way to create a sudoku 9x9 checker to check if there are any reoccurring numbers. I need to make sure that there are 9 numbers in each column and that they are between the numbers 1 and 9

Comment: You can use `pass` instead of `leg = leg + 0` or for others.

Comment: or you can negate the condition to avoid having the else clause.

Comment: by the way, for which lines, it give that error? can you add full traceback?

Comment: it gave this error:File "E:/Computer Programming/Assignment/check 2.py", line 22, in <module>
    cols = [[row[i] for row in infile] for i in[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]
  File "E:/Computer Programming/Assignment/check 2.py", line 22, in <listcomp>
    cols = [[row[i] for row in infile] for i in[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]
  File "E:/Computer Programming/Assignment/check 2.py", line 22, in <listcomp>
    cols = [[row[i] for row in infile] for i in[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: also about working on a sudoku "checker" you can do a lot more by [implementing](https://kunigami.wordpress.com/2013/04/28/the-algorithm-x-and-the-dancing-links/) the [dancing links](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0011047v1.pdf) [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links) by [Don Knuth](http://cs.stanford.edu/~uno/)

Comment: can you update your question with the full stacktrace *and* error properly formatted so it is readable?

Comment: and can you fix your indentation? is line 22 inside `check()` function or outside of it?

Answer (score 2):

first, a few comments:

**never** do:

```
cols = [[row[i] for row in infile] for i in[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]]
```

but do:

```
 cols = [[row[i] for row in infile] for i in range(0,9)]
```

- never call a variable the same name as a function you've defined in your code `check` and `check()`
- don't write code at the module level, but embed everything in functions, and call the entry point function at the end of the file after the `if __name__ == "__main__"` condition (so in case you want to import your module in another module, you don't execute module level code).
- don't open files without closing them, instead use the context manager: `with open('myfile', 'r') as f: ...`
- your code features an useless use of `while`... or at least a wrong use (do you really mean to loop forever on an exception?) use command line arguments instead, that will make the shell help your user choose a file that does *actually* exists.

now I've made all that clear, here's about your actual question:

`infile` is a file object (if I can read correctly your mis-indented python code), thus every line - called `row` here - of `infile` is just a string.

So if you have an empty line or a line that is less than 9 columns, you're likely to get `row[i]` out of boundaries.

here's a take at refactoring your code, though I've left a number of wrong design over:

```
    def check(infile):
        count = 0
        for j in range (0,9):
            for n in range(0,9):
                if infile[j].count(infile[j][n]) <= 1:
                    count = count + 0
                else:
                    count = count + 1

    def inputs():
        x = raw_input()
        ls = []
        while x != '':
            x1 =x.split(' ')
            ls.append(x1)
            if len(infile) >=9:
                print (check(infile))
                infile = []
                x = raw_input()

    def check_grid():
        cols = [[row[i] for row in infile] for i in range(0,9)]
        leg = 0
        for i in range(0,9):
            for j in range(0,9):
                if cols[i].count(cols[i][j]) <= 1:
                    leg = leg + 0
                else:
                        leg = leg + 1

        angel = []
        for t in range(3):
            ang = infile[t]
            for u in range(3):
                angel.append(ang[u])

                foot = 0
                for be in range(9):
                    if angel.count(angel[be]) <= 1:
                        foot = foot + 0
                    else:
                            foot = foot + 1


        if count + leg + foot == 0:
            print("Valid")
        else:
            print ("Invalid")

        inputs()

    def sudoku_checker():
        try:
            file = input("Enter a filename: ") 
            fi = open(file, "r")
            infile = fi.read()
            grid = [list (i) for i in infile.split()] #Puts the sudoku puzzle into a list in     order to check that the total number is valid
            # Counts the amount of numbers in the sudoku puzzle
            print("The total number in this puzzle is:",len(grid))
            check_grid()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print ("The inputted file does not exist")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sudoku_checker()
```